# How to stop webdriverIo test runner from closing the brower

Tags: webdriver-io

WebdriverIo testrunner closes the browser after finishing the test. Is there a way to change this default option?

Comment: There is a issue about it on github. Here is the link hope it can helps you. https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/958

Answer (score 2):

You could throw a `browser.debug()` at the end of your test, which will pause test execution until you exit out of it.

Comment: thats what i am doing right now. I thought there should be something i can do in configuration file or wdio.conf.js..

Comment: This does not work

Comment: You need to await the call `await browser.debug()`.